# How to fill the fields of the form based on the value selected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have created a form in `activeadmin` as follows. When I select the `bkid` of the customer, the fields `customer name`, `mobile number`, `total amount`, and `amount paid` have to be filled automatically in the form.

```html
form :class => 'form_inline' do |f|
 f.inputs do
  f.input :bkid, :label => 'Booking Id',  :as => :select, :collection => Package.all.map{|u| ["#{u.bkid}"]}
   f.input :firstName, :as => :string, :label => 'First name', :class => 'same'
     f.input :lastName, :as => :string, :label => 'Last name', :class => 'same'
       f.input :mobile, :as => :string, :label => 'Mobile no', :class => 'same'
         f.input :totalAmount, :as => :string, :label => 'Total Amount', :class => 'same'
           f.input :amountPaid, :as => :string, :label => 'Amount Paid', :class => 'same'
             f.input :currentPayment, :as => :string, :label => 'Current Payment', :class => 'same'
   # f.input :accountcode_id, :label => 'Acc_code', :as => :select, :collection => Accountcode.all.map{|u| ["#{u.accountcode}, #{u.accountname}"]}
    
   br
     f.submit :value => 'submit'
end

 end
```

**How can I achieve this using ajax?**